# How do I pass in populated list as a parameter in an object constructor?

Tags: java, list, constructor

I have a java class that I am setting up to store LoL champions in a project also using lombok (thus the lack of getters and setters) and Spring. The class looks like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Champion {
    @Id
    private String champName;
    private String role;
    private List<String> type; // <--- how do I populate this?
    private String phrase;
    private List<Champion> counterTo; //<--- or this?
    private List<Champion> counteredBy;// <-- you get the idea.

}
```

I'm overriding the run() method from spring using commandLineRunner in my main application class but I don't know how to populate the lists when I invoke the constructor using Spring's .save() method when persisting into my MongoDB. Can anyone help?

Here is the main class below for context:

```
public class PlaygroundApplication  implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired ChampionRepository repo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PlaygroundApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String...args){
        repo.deleteAll();

        //repo.save("CHAMPION_ENTITY_GOES_HERE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can try new a object and set the param it or Custom constructor

Comment: I ended up using new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList()) and making the lists of Strings and not champion entities.Thanks!